# convertir render_pdf para que obtenga una lista

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

necesito modificar el render_pdf para que reciba los datos que están guardados en una lista, ya que actualmente no me muestra ninguna información .
mi codigo es el siguiente:

### Views.py

```
class PDFprueba(View):

def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    datos = []

    for mascota in Mascota.objects.all() :
        datos.append(
            {
            'nombre' : mascota.nombre,
            'sexo' : mascota.sexo,
            }
            )
    return render_pdf('pdf/pdf.html',{'datos': datos})
```

### render_pdf

```
def render_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
template = get_template(template_src)
html  = template.render(context_dict)
result = BytesIO()

pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode('UTF-8')), result)
if not pdf.err:
    return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

Comment: te sugiero hacer un "print datos" antes del return render_pdf(.......)

Comment: para verificar que en efecto estes enviado todo los datos deseados

Comment: Listo, ya lo soluciones, muchas gracias

Comment: @JoseRicardoFlorezLeon publica tu solución para que la pregunta no quede abierta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Mi solución:

El proyecto no me mandaba la informacion que estaba en el modelo hacia un pdf, Me falto llamar el modelo a la clase.

Tambien me faltaba obtener el pk para imprimir la informacion de la mascota y no de todas las mascotas que estaban en el sistema.

el codigo es el siguiente:

```
class PDFprueba(View):
model = Mascota

def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    pk = self.kwargs.get('pk',0)
    QuerySet = self.model.objects.filter(id=pk)
    datos = []
    for mascota in QuerySet :
        datos.append({
            "id": mascota.id,
            "nombre" : mascota.nombre,
            "sexo" : mascota.sexo
            })

    return render_pdf('pdf/pdf.html',{'datos': datos})
```

no modifique el archivo "render_pdf"